# How to download a file via FTP and save it locally only if it does not exist already?

Tags: file, python-3.x, ftplib

So, I'm downloading some data files from an ftp server. I need to daily go in and retrieve new files and save them on my pc, but only the new ones.

Code so far:

```
from ftplib import FTP
import os

ftp = FTP('ftp.example.com')
ftp.login()
ftp.retrlines('LIST')
filenames = ftp.nlst()

for filename in filenames:
    if filename not in ['..', '.']:
        local_filename = os.path.join('C:\\Financial Data\\', filename)
        file = open(local_filename, mode = 'x')
        ftp.retrbinary('RETR '+ filename, file.write)
```

I was thinking of using `if not os.path.exists()` but I need the os.path.joint for this to work. Using open() with mode = 'x' as above, I get the following err message: "FileExistsError: [Errno 17] File exists"

Is error handling the way to go, or is there a neat trick that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I landed on the following solution:

```
filenames_ftp = ftp.nlst()
filenames_loc = os.listdir("C:\\Financial Data\\")
filenames = list(set(filenames_ftp) - set(filenames_loc))
```